# Major upgrade rollback

Tags: wix

In WIX project I have an custom action that works on SQL server with some data and in some cases faills.
If I have version 1.0 installed and I want to upgrade to 2.0 and the custom action faill then the rollback is called, but in place of remaing the 1.0 binaries/registry entry/services all data is erased and I have nothing installed.
What I must change that after rollback the version 1.0 to remain installed and working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should place [RemoveExistingProducts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) between the InstallExecute action and the InstallFinalize action.